# Change function to find image

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, find

In my example, if you click on one of the alt images, I am looking to get the checkmark image to appear. Right now my on change event is registering (see console), but the image `.checkmark-img` is not being found or faded in. The `fadeBoolToggle` function is to fadeIn out if active.

This code is meant to be allow only one checkbox checked at once. So when someone clicks on an input, it unchecks all inputs and then checks the one clicked.

```
 $('.option-check').not(this).prop('checked', false).closest('.product-wrap').find('.checkmark-img').fadeBoolToggle(false);
   this.checked = true;
   $(this).closest('.product-wrap').find('.checkmark-img').fadeBoolToggle(true);
```

Does anyone see why my image is not fading in when one of the alt images are clicked?

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bozvoeju/1/)

```js
 jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function(bool) {
   return bool ? this.fadeIn(400) : this.fadeOut(400);
 }

 $('.option-check').on('change', function() {
   $('.option-check').not(this).prop('checked', false).closest('.product-wrap').find('.checkmark-img').fadeBoolToggle(false);
   this.checked = true;
   $(this).closest('.product-wrap').find('.checkmark-img').fadeBoolToggle(true);
   var test = $('.option-check:checked').val();
   console.log('option check clicked');
   console.log(test);
 });
```

```css
.product-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.checkmark-img {
  display: none;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.package-check-toggle {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.calendar-option img {
  margin: 20px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

.product-check,
.calendar-check,
.option-check {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calendar-option">
  <div class="product-wrap">
    <label for="flag-option" class="package-check-toggle">
      <img src='images/cal-flag.jpg' alt='A' class='pg-preview-img'>
      <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/835-200.png" class="checkmark-img">
      <p class="calendar-option-push"></p>
      <cite>A</cite>
    </label>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="option-check" id='flag-option' value='A'>
</div>
<div class="calendar-option">
  <div class="product-wrap">
    <label for="nickel-option" class="package-check-toggle">
     <img src='images/cal-nickel.jpg' alt='Brushed Nickel & Black' class='pg-preview-img'>
     <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/835-200.png" class="checkmark-img">
      <p class="calendar-option-push"></p>
      <cite>B</cite>
    </label>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="option-check" id='nickel-option' value='B'>
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log`-ing `$(this).closest('.product-wrap').find('.checkmark-img')` to see what it returns? I bet it returns a function, not an element, which basically means it doesn't find any `.checkmark-img` in `$(this).closest('.product-wrap')`.

Comment: It is `.checkmark-img`. Where do you see ing?

Comment: When doing `console.log($(this).closest('.product-wrap').find('.checkmark-img'));` I get this to return `[prevObject: r.fn.init[0]]`

Comment: Exactly. Both your selectors return no elements. They return an empty jQuery wrapper.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Why isn't the selected input being made into `this`? Any idea what else I could do?

Comment: You don't need checkboxes, you don't need jQuery for this. Just use plain radio inputs sharing the same name and you're done.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu How could I get the image to fadeIn/out then?

Comment: I still get `1[prevObject: r.fn.init[0]]` in the console when changing the input type to radio and using the same name.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Any idea?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] of your problem. One where I could actually verify it.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu The code I posted is minimal?? That is how my code is structured and it has been stripped down to the bones to display the issue I am having.

Comment: I think you're using image links that only work for you. Everyone else sees some broken image placeholders. It's utterly broken. Try it in incognito. For me it's unusable and I don't think anyone else can make any sense of it.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu The alt images are irrelevant. However, I did include substitute image links for the image that is supposed to fadeIn, so it will clearly be verifiable when the images are shown.

Comment: Well, Paul, it looks like you are right and I am wrong. Most probably, your question will get a lot of answers in the immediate future. Unless I'm wrong. Again!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) returns the closest of the current item's parents, including current object itself, which matches the selector.

Because you placed your `<input>`s outside `.product-wrap` divs...

```
$(this).closest('.product-wrap')
```

... returns empty.

Working example:

```js
jQuery.fn.fadeBoolToggle = function(bool) {
   return bool ? this.fadeIn(400) : this.fadeOut(400);
 }

 $('.option-check').on('change', function() {
   $(this).closest('.product-wrap').find('.checkmark-img').fadeBoolToggle(true);
   var test = $('.option-check:checked').val();
   console.log('option check clicked');
   console.log(test);
 });
```

```css
.product-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.checkmark-img {
  display: none;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.package-check-toggle {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.calendar-option img {
  margin: 20px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

.product-check,
.calendar-check,
.option-check {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calendar-option">
  <div class="product-wrap">
    <label for="flag-option" class="package-check-toggle">
      <img src='images/cal-flag.jpg' alt='A' class='pg-preview-img'>
      <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/835-200.png" class="checkmark-img">
      <p class="calendar-option-push"></p>
      <cite>A</cite>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" class="option-check" id='flag-option' name='check-option' value='A'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="calendar-option">
  <div class="product-wrap">
    <label for="nickel-option" class="package-check-toggle">
     <img src='images/cal-nickel.jpg' alt='Brushed Nickel & Black' class='pg-preview-img'>
     <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/835-200.png" class="checkmark-img">
      <p class="calendar-option-push"></p>
      <cite>B</cite>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" class="option-check" id="nickel-option" name='check-option' value='B'>
  </div>
```

When facing such issues in the future, consider using `console.log` methodically. I started with

```
console.log($(this).closest('.product-wrap').is('.product-wrap'))
```

If this would have returned true, I'd have moved on to

```
console.log($(this).closest('.product-wrap').find('.checkmark-img').is('.checkmark-img'))
```

... and so on.

---

**Note:** Even though it reproduced the issue, your snippet looked like it was broken and it stopped everyone, including me, from taking a closer look. Whether you take something out of that, it's totally up to you.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! Yes, I narrowed it down to the `.closest`, but kept changing the selector, thinking it was the issue. I just thought of something...I could have used `.siblings()`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could use `$(this).prev().find('.checkmark-img')` if you insist on the original markup. But having labels and inputs at the same level makes a lot of sense to me. In time I learned keeping things as simple as possible is always a win.

Comment: No preference. Just thinking of alternative methods to my original code. This is with the siblings code. https://jsfiddle.net/bozvoeju/2/ Thanks for the alternative method and help!